# How would I order a MySQL query by letter and number, sorting 100 as higer than 010?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

We have product codes that go as follows:

- AGE100 *(stands for AGE 1.00 ounce)*
- AGE050 *(stands for AGE 0.50 ounce)*
- AGE025 *(stands for AGE 0.25 ounce)*
- AGE010 *(stands for AGE 0.10 ounce)*

So on and so forth. I would like the database to return them alphabet first, then by the number code at the end, so KR100 would be lower than AGE050.

My current query,

```
 SELECT * FROM  'prices' ORDER BY  'code' ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Returns:

1. AGE010
2. AGE025
3. AGE050
4. AGE100
5. KR100

How would I make it sort the numbers in the code properly?

Comment: Remove all non-numeric characters, convert to a number then do a standard binary sort...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you want it to return?

Comment: Could you add the complete sort order that would be correct?

Comment: it is two sorts - ASC on the char portion, and DESC on the numeric portion.  first chore is to split them - then the ordering will be easy

Comment: @Dagon: I found a solution there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To sort descending by the number portion:

```
SELECT * FROM  'prices' ORDER BY SUBSTRING('code', -3) DESC
```

and the first 2 chars

```
SELECT * FROM  'prices' ORDER BY SUBSTRING('code', 1,2) ASC
```

so this should give you a something close:

```
SELECT * FROM  'prices' ORDER BY SUBSTRING('code', 1,2) ASC, SUBSTRING('code', -3) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To place items in a specific order you could use an `sortby` column in the database that you can change to finely adjust the order that the rows should be pull out in.

Example

```
SELECT * FROM  'prices' ORDER BY  'code' ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

would become

```
SELECT * FROM  'prices' ORDER BY  'sortby' ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This field would be an INT and would make it much easier to get the desired order.

Answer (score -1):

Since `natsort()` doesn't work with multidimensional arrays, you can try:

`uksort($array, 'strnatcasecmp');`